# Ordering the results of Inner join

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I currently have the following query:

```
select X.sellerID, x.Category, y.Award_Year, Y.Award
from Y
inner join
    X on Y.Seller_ID=X.sellerID
```

Which give me this results:

[image]

How can I write a query to get Top 3 seller and the amount of awards recieved in 2017. Following is expected result:

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: You need to use Group By, Having and Order by clause here. You need to read about them and apply knowledge to solve this.

Comment: Why isn't seller_id 10 not in the expected output? That seller also has one award in 2017 just like sellers 4 and 9 - what is the logic to remove sellers from the list if they have the same number of awards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the top 3 sellers by descending order (i.e. most awards in top) and you could do a flashy pivot thing with filtering on year to get a more general query, but I suspect something like this one would be more suitable at this level..

The top 3 clause will differ between different DB Engines

MSSQL : TOP (nr) directly after SELECT

Oracle: FETCH FIRST nr ROWS ONLY last in statement

mysql: LIMIT nr last in statement

etc....

FOR MSSQL it would be something like

```
SELECT TOP (3) sellerID, Category, Award_Year, COUNT(Award_Year) Awards
from Y y 
inner join
    X x on y.Seller_ID=x.sellerID
WHERE Award_Year = 2017
GROUP BY x.sellerID, x.Category, y.Award_Year
Order By COUNT(Award_Year) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Your query is very simple to understand for a newbie like me.

Comment: @user1694674 . . . You should learn to use better table aliases than `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP(3) A.Id, A.category, count(A.Award) AS 'Award in 2017'
FROM (
    SELECT X.sellerID AS ID, x.Category, y.Award_Year, Y.Award
    FROM Y
    INNER JOIN X on Y.Seller_ID=X.sellerID
) A
GROUP BY A.Id, A.category
ORDER BY count(A.Award) DESC
```

Depending on your actual DBMS version, you may need to amend it.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful input. I'm still new to this yet look at your query I learnt alot.

Comment: @CecilHigwind no problem. let me know if it works.What database system are you using? I assumed SQL server